# Finding the no of V-shaped Permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification

Consider $n$ distinct real numbers: $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n},$ A permutation $([1],[2], \ldots,[n])$ of the indices $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ is said to $V$ -shaped if there exists an integer $r \quad(1 \leq r \leq n)$ such that $a_{[1]} \geq a_{[2]} \geq \ldots \geq a_{[r-1]} \geq a_{[r]} \leq a_{[r+1]} \leq \ldots \leq a_{[n]} .$ Find the total of such $\mathrm{V}$
shaped permutations.

**My Approach**,
*As the given n numbers are distinct, so $a_{[r]}$ would be the lowest number
So the lowest number can take 1,2,....n positions
If it takes the i th position then it has (i-1) items to left. So we need to choose (i-1) items out of n-1 items. So $^{n-1}C_{r-1}$ now as all items are distinct no permutation among these choosen items.*

$Am$ $I$ $correct?$

Comment: You are correct, but so you have to add over the possible $r's$ no?

Comment: yes! it will be a summation.

Comment: Cool, i put as an answer how to think about this without separate into cases. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. For completion i will put the result then. You end up with
$$\sum _{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}=2^{n-1},$$
so you can think of this by selecting a subset of $\{a_1,\cdots ,a_n\}$ excluding the minimal element. So there are $n-1$ choices and so $2^{n-1}$ choices to choose the set that is gonna decrease to the minimal element. The remaining elements you put them in ascending order.

Comment: yeah! absolutely correct. thanks for your response